# encryptar datos y desencriptar datos en el blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy usando **laravel 5.7** utilizando el **auth**  por-defecto y quiero que todos mis registros esten **encryptados** ya pude encriptarlos pero al momento de iniciar sesión con el correo encryptado no se puede  o de mostrar el nombre del usuario cuando inicie sesión quisiera saber como lo podria desencriptar.

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => Crypt::encrypt($data['name']),
        'email' => Crypt::encrypt($data['email']),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para desencriptarlo simplemente utilizas el método decrypt, disponible en el mismo facade:

```
Crypt::decrypt($data['name']);
```

Como referencia, este es el código de dicho método:

```
/**
 * Decrypt the given value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $payload
 * @param  bool  $unserialize
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
 */
public function decrypt($payload, $unserialize = true)
{
    $payload = $this->getJsonPayload($payload);

    $iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);

    // Here we will decrypt the value. If we are able to successfully decrypt it
    // we will then unserialize it and return it out to the caller. If we are
    // unable to decrypt this value we will throw out an exception message.
    $decrypted = \openssl_decrypt(
        $payload['value'], $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv
    );

    if ($decrypted === false) {
        throw new DecryptException('Could not decrypt the data.');
    }

    return $unserialize ? unserialize($decrypted) : $decrypted;
}
```

---

En Blade se puede utilizar el helper `decrypt()`:

```
decrypt($data['name']);
```

Si se necesita usar el facade, se debe incluir el namespace completo.

Comment: pero como desencrypto direcctamente desde el blade ?

Comment: Eso no es lo que dice la pregunta.

Comment: listo ya lo coloque gracias

Comment: Ya agregué lo que necesita.